# sorting pd dataframe based on lists sizes of column and another column int vaues

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of two columns:

- one column consists of integer values
- the other of  lists of different sizes as values.

I want to sort the frame records according to max int value and max list size in descending order. I tried to paste the data, but it was not understandable.

Thanks

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6910411)

Answer (score 0):

Im using this as a test dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5,2,5], 'b': [[1,4,6,7], [2,6], [1,7,4]]})

   a             b
0  5  [1, 4, 6, 7]
1  2        [2, 6]
2  5     [1, 7, 4]
```

One way you can do this is to calculate the length of your lists, and then sort your dataframe by both the lengths and your integer column:

```
df['lens'] = df['b'].str.len()

df.sort_values(['a', 'lens'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

df = df.drop(columns='lens').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which will give you this:

```
   a             b
0  5  [1, 4, 6, 7]
1  5     [1, 7, 4]
2  2        [2, 6]
```

Comment: Thank You Simon, I need the lists with bigger sizes and support of larger than zero to be first. Here is a ample of the data support. the int value is the support value: the value of colomn1.
itemsets
0
0.576923
[first_name]
1
0.423077
[hire_date]
2
0.384615
[first_name, hire_date]
3
0.384615
[first_name, last_name]
4
0.384615
[emp_no]

Comment: I dont understand. In my example the largest list is sorted first, and so is the largest int value. How should it look instead?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5,2,5], 'b': [[1,4,6,7], [2,6], [1,7,4]]})

df = df.loc[np.lexsort((df['b'].map(len), df['a']))[::-1]]

print(df)

#    a             b
# 0  5  [1, 4, 6, 7]
# 2  5     [1, 7, 4]
# 1  2        [2, 6]
```

This is likely to perform better for larger dataframes.

Note, using `numpy.lexsort`, the sequence of ordering is reversed, i.e. the above code first sorts by `a`, then length of lists in `b`.